# VLC syntax to transcode and stream to stdout?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ffmpeg, vlc, libvlc

**Goal:** I am trying to use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) as a local server to expand the video capabilities of an app created with `Adobe AIR`, `Flex` and `Actionscript`.  I am using `VLC` to stream to `stdout`and reading that output from within my app.

[VLC Streaming capabilities](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html)
[VLC Flash Video](https://wiki.videolan.org/Flash_Video/)
[Stream VLC to Website with asf and Flash](https://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_VLC_to_Website_with_asf_and_Flash)

**Status:** I am able to launch `VLC` as a background process and control it through its [remote control interface](https://wiki.videolan.org/documentation:modules/rc/) ([more detail](https://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/controlling-vlc-via-rc-remote-control-interface-using-a-unix-domain-socket-and-no-programming/)). I can load, transcode and stream a local video file. The example app below is a barebones testbed demonstrating this.

**Issue:** I am getting data in to my app but it is not rendering as video. I don't know if it is a problem with my VLC commands or with writing to/reading from `stdout`. This technique of reading from `stdout` in AIR works (with `ffmpeg` for example).

One of the various transcoding commands I have tried:

```
-I rc  // remote control interface  
-vvv   // verbose debuging  
--sout  // transcode, stream to stdout 
"#transcode{vcodec=FLV1}:std{access=file,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=-}"
```

This results in data coming into to my app but for some reason it is not rendering as video when using `appendBytes` with the `NetStream` instance.

If instead I write the data to an .flv file, a valid file is created – so the broken part seems to be writing it to `stdout`. **One thing I have noticed: I am not getting metadata through the stdout`method. If I play the file created with the command below, I do see metadata.**

```
// writing to a file
var output:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("stream.flv");
var outputPath:String = output.nativePath;
"#transcode{vcodec=FLV1}:std{access=file,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=" + outputPath + "}");
```

---

Hoping someone sees where I am going wrong here.

---

**Update 1:** Just to add some more detail (!) – I took a look at the .flv file that is generated to examine the metadata. It appears at the head of the file as shown below. I have the correct `onMetaData` handler set up and see a trace of this data if I play the file from disk. **I do not see this trace when reading from `stdout` and `NetStream` is in `Data Generation` mode.** Is it possible that it isn't getting sent to `stdout` for some reason? I've tried generating my own header and appending that before the stream starts – I may not have the header format correct.

[image]

---

**Update 2:** So in my `AIR` app I was able to crudely parse the incoming `stdout` stream coming from `VLC`. I wanted to see if the FLV header data was being sent – and it appears that it is. I don't know if it is in the correct format, etc. but as I mention above, if I write to an .flv file instead of `stdout`, a valid .flv file is created.

Completely at a loss now – have tried everything I could think of and followed up every web link I could find on the issues involved. Alas – so close and it would have been so cool to leverage `VLC` from within `AIR`.

---

**Update 3:** Per `VC ONE's` suggestion, I have used his/her example code to check the incoming bytes for correct data. I get a massive string (1000's of chars) but these are the first ones:

```
    What I get:
    464C560105000000090000000012000111000000000000000200
    46 4C 56 01 05 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 // check outs  

    What it should be:
    46 4C 56 01 05 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00
```

---

**Note:** In order to get this to work in AIR, you need to define the app profile as "extendedDesktop"

---

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="1024" height="768"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       applicationComplete="onApplicationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            public var dataIn:Number = 0;
            public var dataTotal:Number = 0;
            private var processExe:File;
            private var processArgs:Vector.<String>;
            private var process:NativeProcess;
            private var nc:NetConnection;
            private var ns:NetStream;
            private var vid:Video;

            private var videoPath:String; // video to be streamed

            protected function onApplicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                var testFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test.mp4");
                if (testFile.exists){
                    videoPath = testFile.nativePath;
                }

                setUpNetStream();
                createNativeProcess();
                startNativeProcess();
            }

            protected function setUpNetStream():void {
                nc = new NetConnection();
                nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, errorHandler);
                nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, connStatusHandler);
                nc.connect(null);

                ns = new NetStream(nc);
                ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, errorHandler);
                ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, streamStatusHandler);

                var client:Object = new Object();
                client.onMetaData = onMetaDataHandler;
                ns.client = client;

                vid = new Video(640,480);
                vid.x= 100;
                vid.y = 200;

                this.stage.addChild(vid);

                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
                ns.play(null);
            }

            private function createNativeProcess():void {
                if(NativeProcess.isSupported) {
                    // This is for OSX; 
                    var pathToVLC:String = "utils/OSX/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC";
                    processExe = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(pathToVLC);

                    if (processExe.exists){
                        process = new NativeProcess();
                        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 
                        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, onErrorData); 
                        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onOutputData); 
                        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onOutputData); 
                        process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
                        process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR, onIOError);
                    } else {
                        trace("process not found");
                    }
                } else {
                    trace("Native Process not supported");
                }
            }

            private function startNativeProcess():void {
                processArgs = new Vector.<String>();
                processArgs.push("-I rc");
                processArgs.push("-vvv"); // verbose debug output
                processArgs.push("--sout");

                // -------TO WRITE TO A FILE ----------
                // file to playback from
                //var output:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("stream.flv");
                //var outputPath:String = output.nativePath;
                //processArgs.push("#transcode{vcodec=FLV1}:std{access=file,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=" + outputPath + "}");

                processArgs.push("#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,acodec=mp3}:gather:std{access=file,mux=flv,dst=-}");
                processArgs.push("--sout-keep");

                // ------VARIATIONS-------
                //processArgs.push("#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,acodec=mp3}:std{access=file,mux=flv,dst=-}");
                //processArgs.push("#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=512,acodec=mp3,ab=128,samplerate=44100}:std{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},access=file,dst=-}");

                var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = processExe;
                nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;
                process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

                // add video to playlist and play
                process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes("add " + videoPath + " \n" );
                process.standardInput.writeUTFBytes("play" + "\n" );
            }

            public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void { 
                if (process && process.running){
                    if (process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable){
                        var videoStream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                        process.standardOutput.readBytes(videoStream,0, process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);

                        dataIn = videoStream.length;
                        dataTotal+= dataIn;
                        report.text = String("Current Bytes: " + dataIn + "\t Total Bytes: "+ dataTotal);

                        if (videoStream.length){
                            ns.appendBytes(videoStream);
                        }
                        //trace(ns.info);
                    }   
                }
            }

            private function errorHandler(e:AsyncErrorEvent):void {
                trace('ERROR: ' + e.text);
            }

            private function connStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
                trace('CONN_STATUS: ' + e.info.code);

                switch(e.info.code){
                    case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                        //onFinishSetup();
                        break;
                }
            }

            private function streamStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
                trace('STREAM_STATUS: ' + e.info.code);
            }

            private function streamMetadataHandler(info:Object):void {
                for (var key:String in info) {
                    trace("STREAM_METADATA: " + key + "=" + info[key]);
                }               
            }

            public function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void {
                if (process && process.running){
                    trace(process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable));
                }
            }
            public function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
                trace(event.toString());
            }

            private function onMetaDataHandler(metadata:Object):void {
                trace("### Begin Metadata listing : FLV Entries ### "  );
                for (var entry:* in metadata) 
                {
                    var value:Object = metadata[ entry ];
                    trace(" > " + entry + " : " + value);
                }
                trace("### End of Metadata listing for this FLV ### "  );
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="report" x="25" y="25" fontSize="18" />
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: so, I have not tried your actual scenario... but did have a thought I would run by you.  When I have had troubles with a file not stream reading, yet plays fine when loaded as a whole file... the problem has ALWAYS been that the video MOOV ATOM data was at the end of the encoded video instead of at the beginning. And since you mentioned "I don't see metadata" I thought I would bring this up and see if it potentially applies. If it looks like this may apply to you... check out qtfaststart https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart to convert them with data in front.

Comment: its not VLC.  I had this issue with various streaming sources. It's the mp4 source file itself.  By default, a lot of encoders put the data at the end of the mp4 wrapper... and if you try to stream that... the receiver has no metadata to work with.  If you use that tool I gave you a link to on your mp4, it will move the data from the end of the mp4 to the beginning... and happy streaming begins! (if this is your issue as well)

Comment: Well it was a thought.  I've done this quite a bit with ffmpeg and other than the metadata issue, all of my woes came from properly matching / specifying input and output codec info. (which I see you are already playing with).  If you don't have this resolved by tomorrow... I will have some time after work to set up VLC on my machine and play with a stream and see if I can help you tackle it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your other Question's comments you asked for my thoughts :

I noticed in your code you're running VLC process under OSX environment. 
 
On Windows PC be aware that `-I rc` does not later respond to `standardInput` commands sent. I'm a Windows user so cannot help with that part.

Tried using `--no-rc-fake-tty` or even `--rc-fake-tty`, VLC still did not respond to `stdout` on PC.

You want to do playback & seeking within VLC but watch result in AS3 (like a projection screen), right? but I'm not even sure VLC will give you back FLV tags starting from your selected time stamps etc (by seeking you are accessing an FLV tag of a specific timestamp & the related a/v data)...

Other FFmpeg/Mencoder powered players like MPlayer I tested only send back "status" text data into `stdout` during playback (so cannot be fed to `NetStream` decoder for display).

> I was able to crudely parse the incoming `stdout` stream coming from
>   VLC. I wanted to see if the FLV header data was being sent – and it
>   appears that it is. I don't know if it is in the correct format, etc.

Check the bytes: (a valid FLV header begins with `46 4C 56 01 05 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00`)

Just update your Question with a copy-paste of the "bytes check" result from the below function. Then easier to tell you if it's playable or maybe you need some alternative.

1) Setup some public (or private) vars...

- Make a `public var temp_String : String = "";`
- Make a `public var videoStream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();`

2) Replace your function `onOutputData` with below code...

```
public function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    if (process && process.running)
    {
        if (process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable)
        {
            //# make a private/public bytearray outside of this function 
            //var videoStream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

            process.standardOutput.readBytes(videoStream, videoStream.length, process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);

            dataIn = process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable; 
            dataTotal += dataIn;
            //report.text = String("Current Bytes: " + dataIn + "\t Total Bytes: "+ dataTotal);

            if (videoStream.length >= 1000 )
            {
                //ns.appendBytes(videoStream);

                temp_String = bytes_toString(videoStream);
                trace("bytes checking : " + "\n");
                trace( temp_String ); //see hex of FLV bytes

                //# temporary pausing of progress events 
                process.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);
            }
            //trace(ns.info);
        }
    }
}
```

Supporting function `bytes_toString` code :

```
public function bytes_toString ( ba:ByteArray ) : String
{
    var str_Hex:String = "";    var len:uint = ba.length;

    ba.position = 0;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        var n:String=ba.readUnsignedByte().toString(16); 

        if(n.length<2) //padding
        { n="0"+n; }    str_Hex += n ;
    }

    return str_Hex.toUpperCase();
}
```

Some other notes :

Each firing of progress events only captures 32kb / 64kb packets of incoming `stdout` bytes at a time.

You make your `videoStream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();` outside of the progressEvent so that each event firing does not make a new byteArray (which discards the old data that may be needed later for a full FLV tag).

Don't write each packet to `0` position since that will overwrite existing data. Add to the end-of existing by using `videoStream.length` as new writing position.

```
process.standardOutput.readBytes(videoStream, videoStream.length, process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
```

Also `if (videoStream.length){ ns.appendBytes(videoStream); }` is kinda dangerous. Any incomplete data (of header, frame or whatever) will jam the NetStream decoder if you append too soon. It will not restart unless you reset everything and begin again (re-append bytes of full FLV header, full frame tag, etc).

Comment: Wow you really are getting an FLV file!! Phew, but I bet that's from transcode, isn't it? Does `stdout` give anything if you just play an FLV with `RC` mode? If so then seeking might still be possible but I can't test this side. If transcoding / FFmpeg works fine, is the only issue remaining about using AS3 for accurate seeking (to any seconds of duration instead of usual keyframes-only behaviour)?

Comment: Regardless of input format always choose output to FLV (h.264) cos appendBytes designed for FLV format only. Confirm again: **without transcoding** & in RC mode if you use `add filename.flv` then `play` you will get bytes from `stdout`? I want to see those play bytes. If they're a frame tag then you could really make progress with playback. So like how you showed me the FLV header bytes to confirm correctness, use one comment box to copy-paste as many of those "to be appended" _play_ bytes as you can fit here. I'll check what you got.

Comment: Ok –I am not confident that I have the `VLC` cmd correct but using `#standard{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},access=file,dst=-}` (**no transcoding**) I get: `564C43206D6564696120706C6179657220322E` as the first bit of a really long string. Ran it several times: same result. So that doesn't look right. Using `#standard{mux=flv,access=file,dst=-}` (no `ffmpeg` I get `564C43206D6564696120706C6179657220` – which looks to be the same. So that's broken, right?

Comment: This is the "translation" of your above bytes...`VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax.Command Line Interface initialized. Type 'help' for help...> > FLV........................onMetaData` etc, so you _really_ do get an FLV eventually (which can be appended). You just have to **ignore the first 97 bytes** sent cos they're just a copy of that VLC's `rc` welcome screen. Don't know why there are sent but I'll think of a way to crop later-ish (need to leave computer).

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Much appreciated. +1 for finally working solution. About the re-init of byteArray, well it makes sense with FFmpeg on PC, don't know if MacOS is somehow more capable and "just works". My issue is the `new` keyword which I understand makes multiple copies of same variable in memory. An alternative is `videoStream.clear()`, either way you get a blank box to re-fill with new data. Anyways it's all to future-proof an issue that wont / hasn't even happened. Haha. Do what works since _"if it aint broken yet, don't fix"_ etc...

Comment: PS: I'll look into the PC side of things tomorrow. I'm actually interested in seeing these VLC features working with AIR on PC.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I would try, some of which you might have thought of already:

1. Try without debugging turned on, in case that is fouling up your stdout stream.
2. Try a different video format (not FLV) in case it's a format-specific issue. For example, you might try `mpeg4`
3. Try piping your stdout stream to something else, like ffplay to see if the problem is the stream or your receiving app's assumptions about the stream.

Comment: Glad you got it working! VC.One's comment is what I was getting at with my first suggestion there. I believe you can suppress that output with --quiet (Under  Miscellaneous Options here: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/)